# Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf wampserver

Tags: wampserver

Hello everyone I installed wampserver but I can't start the server the icon stay on orange in the logs directory there is no error log 
only install.log 
and there is the message

```
    Installing Apache HTTP Server 2.x with
 DomainName    = example.com
 ServerName    = www.example.com
 ServerAdmin   = admin@example.com
 ServerPort    = 80
 ServerSslPort = 443
 ServerRoot    = c:/Apache24
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/httpd.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/httpd.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/proxy-html.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/proxy-html.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/httpd.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/magic
 to c:/Apache24/conf/magic
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/charset.conv
 to c:/Apache24/conf/charset.conv
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/proxy-html.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/mime.types
 to c:/Apache24/conf/mime.types
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf
```

I hade wamp 64 bit and removed it and install the 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

Those are not messages from an install of WAMPServer. So I would assume that you had tried to install Apache manually but have not uninstalled it before installing WAMPServer.

So basically you have 2 Apache running and the original is probably set to start Automatically at boot time, so WAMPServers Apache cannot get to port 80 as the other Apache has already assigned it.

Uninstall the other Apache and WAMPServer will work.